# why the sub Process couldn't access its data, in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

the output is like this, so strange, as I thought in the run function, it should also output the list data
list running []
append list [1]
list running []
append list [1, 2]
list running []
append list [1, 2, 3]
list running []
append list [1, 2, 3, 4]
list running []
append list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class A(Process):

    def __init__(self):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.list = []

    def append_list(self, item):
        self.list.append(item)
        print 'append list', self.list

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print 'list running', self.list
            import time
            time.sleep(2)
a = A()
a.start()

i = 0
while True:
    i+=1
    import time
    time.sleep(2)
    a.append_list(i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the fact that you are calling a function on the process class, doesn't mean it runs in the sub process.

when you create your A object,  the list is in the main process. when you run `start()` on it, the list gets copied to the child process (well, not exactly, but let's assume it for simplicity). then when the parent process calls the function, you are appending to a list that's only in the memory of the parent process. the one in the child, even though it has the same name, now belongs to a different python process.

If you want to share state between processes, you need to use shared memory objects, or queue objects. see here:

http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: thanks for your answer, and I use pipe to solve this problem. thanks.